# sklearn.manifold.SpectralEmbedding() Distance Metric

Tags: python, scikit-learn

I am a researcher using Scikit Learn's SpectralEmbedding() function to dimensionally reduce my data. I notice that when choosing affinity='nearest_neighbors' the code computes the distance matrix using sklearn.neighbors.kneighbors_graph() with the default distance metric as Minkowski p=2 (Euclidean). I would like to know why that is. I understand that you are able to compute your own affinity matrix, but it is understood that, when working with high dimensional data, using the Euclidean metric is not an adequate metric for representing distance. It is essentially meaningless in such data sets. Metrics such as the correlation distance and cosine distance have been proven to be more accurate at preserving distance. If there is some reasoning behind this decision I would be most interested to know.

Thank you!

Comment: With normalized data, euclidan and cosine are not so different. https://skeptric.com/cosine-is-euclidean/